# Python 3.7complete uninstall

Tags: macos

I am trying to install tensorflow with virtualenv. Did not realize I had previously install python3.7. Now I cannot safely and completely delete it without manually removing files from /LIBRARY. I am not sure if that is the right way to do it. If there is a safe way to clean up the system folders please indicate which.

Comment: Why do you want to remove 3.7?

Comment: py3.7 does not satisfy the requirements for tensorflow.

Comment: It supports 2.7/3.6 though yes? I don't recall anything with 3.7 that broke compatibility. Weird.

Comment: ok, finally got it to work. It was not hard, just a bit confusing installation instructions. Thanks

Comment: @MuhsinAlabbas Welcome to Ask Different! :) I'm just wondering whether you'd like to answer your own question, as it may help others? Feel free to also [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/314870/edit) your original question if it needs to better reflect how you resolved this.